# Flutter, How to make partially dark UI?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

I just want these black dots to be slightly darker (light/dark), not black.

And it's actually not a circle, it's slightly sprayed with an irregular shape (like a light)

is there a smooth way?? thanks!

[image]

(I actually want to put this effects light/dark but it is not exactly shadow, So no need for shadow physics.)

Comment: Can you include another  image of your desire outcome?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, Hi Yeasin, I put new one please refer this

Comment: I will be little complicated, but you can do it using `Transform` and Stack I think

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simply give an opacity for the color you are applying.
**Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)**

```
 Widget blackCircle (){
    return Container(
      width: 70,
      height: 70,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
      ),
    );
   }
```

Comment: Sorry I know this way, But what if you want to give it a more spray-on feel? As if spraying black spray on a certain background

Answer (score 1):

Use [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget, which adds Opacity to child widget, in below example it's the `Container` widget. Opacity is given from values 0.0 to 1.0.

0.0 means no opacity which means the widget will not be visible, 1.0 means the widget will be visible as given, in-between values make it partially dark.

```
Opacity(opacity: 0.2, child: Container(
      width: 60,
      height: 60,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.black),
    ),);
```

Comment: But what if you want to give it a more spray-on feel? As if spraying black spray on a certain background (it's actually not a circle, it's slightly sprayed with an irregular shape (like a dark/light gradiation) )